# How can I escape a single quote in a XAML markup extension property literal?

Tags: .net, xaml, escaping, markup-extensions

I have a value converter that formats numbers (I can't use SP1 yet unfortunately).  It works fine until it gets a percentage.

Here's an example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PercentageComplete,
                          Converter={StaticResource NumberFormatter},
                          ConverterParameter='0.00 %'}" />
```

Unfortunately for me when `Double.ToString` sees a percentage character, it multiplies the number by 100.  In my case, the number is already a percentage and no conversion is needed.

In C#, this would be achieved by escaping the `%` character with a single quote:

```
(99.99).ToString("0.00 %")  // gives -> "9999 %"
(99.99).ToString("0.00 '%") // gives -> "99.99 %"
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use a single quote in the `ConverterParameter` in the above XAML markup extension.  Is there a way of escaping it?  I have tried doubling the single quotes and using a backslash, but both failed to compile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Untested, but have you tried:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PercentageComplete,
                      Converter={StaticResource NumberFormatter},
                      ConverterParameter=&quot;0.00 '%&quot;}" />
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Works like a charm, though I prefer this variant which also works (and I only tried after your suggestion): `ConverterParameter='0.00 &quot;%'`.  Many thanks.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the variant I mention doesn't cause VS to mark subsequent code in red, even though it compiles just fine.

Comment: Ironically I had something similar, but thought it'd work better the other way around, so changed it :)

Answer (score 12):

The below is taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200269.aspx.

**You can escape any character with a backslash.** It does not parse the backslashes but just skips them. So:

- `'foo\'bar'` becomes `foo'bar`;
- `"foo\"bar"` becomes `foo"bar`;
- `'foo\\bar'` becomes `foo\bar`;
- `'foo\nbar'` becomes `foonbar` and not a newline character.

However, markup extension parsing is quite strange. Even though Visual Studio syntax highlighting doesn't support it, any character other than `\{},=` is a valid value character. This means that the following constructions are legal:

- `{MyExtension Name=foo'bar}` (quotes must be the first character to be considered quoting for a string; anywhere else its just copied verbatim);
- `{MyExtension Name=f oo}` (spaces are legal too; this becomes `f oo`);
- `{MyExtension Name=  foo }` (spaces around the value are trimmed; this becomes `foo`);
- `{MyExtension Name=foo\\bar}` (characters after a `\` are copied verbatim, so this becomes `foo\bar`);
- `{MyExtension Name=foo \\ bar}` (this becomes `foo \ bar`);
- `{MyExtension Name=foo \} bar}` (and this becomes `foo } bar`).

Note that the `\` rules apply here too: any character following a `\` is copied verbatim.

Comment: Did you tested this? I have an example here where I want to insert '\t' as a ConverterParameter. '\t' gives me 't' and '\\t' gives me '\\t'.

Comment: Indeed, I cannot duplicate the results as prescribed above.  `<Grid Tag="{local:Testing 'foo \\ bar', PropertyName=foo \\ bar}" />` <-- both constructor and property values return exactly as described, as `foo \\ bar`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use String.Format instead of Double.ToString

```
public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
    string format = (string) parameter;

    return String.Format( format, value );
}
```

And in your binding expression, use the special {} escape sequence:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PercentageComplete, Converter={StaticResource NumberFormatter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:0.00} %'}"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround that avoids the markup extension, though it isn't a direct answer to the question.

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <Binding Path="PercentageComplete"
             Converter="{StaticResource NumberFormatter}"
             ConverterParameter="0.00 '%" />
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```